# Multiple VSS plots in one window

Tags: r, plot, statistics, psych

I tried to compare multiple VSS plots in one window. However the usual procedure with `par(mfrow=c(x,y)` doesn't seem to work. Neither does `layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))`. I took the following example of [William Revelle's website](https://personality-project.org/r/r.vss.html). I had to alter the plot command. It may have changed from `plotVSS` to `VSS.plot` at some stage, whilst the example has not been update.

```
require(psych)
meanloading=.7
ncases=400
par(mfrow=c(2,4))

for (i in 1:4) 
{ x=VSS(VSS.simulate(ncases,36,i,meanloading),rotate="none")
VSS.plot(x,paste(i, " factor no rotation")) }

for (i in 1:4) 
{ x=VSS(VSS.simulate(ncases,36,i,meanloading),rotate="varimax")
VSS.plot(x,paste(i, " factor varimax rotation")) }
```

Any suggestions why I don't get more than one plot in a window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `VSS` is called without the `plot` argument. Hence, the default, `TRUE`, is used. This resets your plot generated with `VSS.plot`. You have to call `VSS` with `plot = FALSE`.

The second problem is the function `VSS.plot` itself. It calls `par` and therefore all plots appear at the same location in the plot frame.

When you remove the first and last line from the `VSS.plot` function, everything will work fine. The code for the modified version, `VSS.plot2` can be found at the end of my answer.

```
require(psych)
meanloading <- .7
ncases <- 400
par(mfrow=c(2,4))

for (i in 1:4) { 
  x <-VSS(VSS.simulate(ncases,36,i,meanloading),rotate="none", plot = FALSE)
  VSS.plot2(x,paste(i, " factor no rotation"))
}

for (i in 1:4) { 
  x <- VSS(VSS.simulate(ncases,36,i,meanloading),rotate="varimax", plot = FALSE)
  VSS.plot2(x,paste(i, " factor varimax rotation")) 
}
```

[image]

---

The modified version of `VSS.plot`:

```
VSS.plot2 <- function (x, title = "Very Simple Structure", line = FALSE) 
{
    #op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    n = dim(x)
    symb = c(49, 50, 51, 52)
    plot(x$cfit.1, ylim = c(0, 1), type = "b", 
         ylab = "Very Simple Structure Fit", 
         xlab = "Number of Factors", pch = 49)
    if (line) 
        lines(x$fit)
    title(main = title)
    x$cfit.2[1] <- NA
    x$cfit.3[1] <- NA
    x$cfit.3[2] <- NA
    x$cfit.4[1] <- NA
    x$cfit.4[2] <- NA
    x$cfit.4[3] <- NA
    lines(x$cfit.2)
    points(x$cfit.2, pch = 50)
    lines(x$cfit.3)
    points(x$cfit.3, pch = symb[3])
    lines(x$cfit.4)
    points(x$cfit.4, pch = symb[4])
    #par(op)
}
```

Comment: Very impressive. Thanks. (I would give +1 but I don't have sufficient "reputation").